# Are airlines allowed to publicly display the first few characters of the last name of their passengers taking a given flight?

Tags: united-states, privacy

I see that United Airlines publicly display the first few characters of the last name of their passengers taking a given flight.

Example from https://www.united.com/en/us/flightstatus/details/855/2020-01-14/LIM/IAH/UA ([mirror](http://archive.is/WCj0w)):

[image]

Are airlines allowed to publicly display the first few characters of the last name of their passengers taking a given flight?

Comment: There is no privacy law in the US that prohibits this, it may be different in the UK/GDPR state.

Comment: To put a finer point on @RonBeyer 's comment, in the USA they could put the full name if they wanted, legally. People might get upset, but it's legal.